# 2 dependent spinner

Tags: android

if i have 2 spinner the second depend in the first
i will retriever the info of the second spinner from MySQL database depend in the choose of first spinner i succuflly get the id of the first spinner but i do not 
how to send it to the other cause it not work with me

i have class MainActivity that have:

```
new LoadAllCourses().execute(); //first spinner generation 
new LoadAllSection().execute(); //second spinner
```

in `class LoadAllCourses extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>`

```
adapter1 = new  MyCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    coursesList);

             spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1); // Set the custom adapter to the spinner

             spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                         HashMap<String, String> map12 = coursesList.get(position);
                          String id3 = map12.get("CourseID");
                            // Do something
                         Log.d("All coursesdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd: ", id3);
                        // Do something

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {

                    }
                });
```

now i want to get the id3 and send it to

```
class LoadAllSection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

but it is not work

how can i solve it if i have as i said

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question, you require the selection on the first spinner to for the basis of a search from a database to populate the second spinner.
 If in adapter 1 (`adapter1 = new  MyCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    coursesList);`) courseList is an array, one can get the selected item from the spinner in the setOnItemSelectedListeneras follows `courseList [position]`.

Having obtained the selected item, you then require a function to perform the query in the database, say `load_all_selection(courseList [position])` which should return an array of results from your database.

Since it returns an array you can define adapter 2 as follows
 `adapter2 = new  MyCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    load_all_selection(courseList [position]));`
and assign it to the second spinner `spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);`

All this can be done from within the setOnItemSelectedListener part, except maybe for the definition of the `load_all_selection(...)` function.

I hope I understood you question and this helps. If it doesn't you can still look around for a different solution.

Comment: yes you understand me but my adapter 2 is inside LoadAllSection how can in LoadAllSection get the d3 so i can retrieve from db

Comment: yes you  understand me but i have class LoadAllSection which have indide it  params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CourseID", id3));  her is id3 it dose not get the value of id3 that inside  LoadAllCourses

Comment: Okay. So they are in two separate classes. What if you create a set_id() function in LoadAllSelection to receive id3 and then the load_all_function() can use the received value to query the database?

Comment: Okay.I think that will be better.

Comment: there a change that i made i make each time i get the id3 i send it to the the class all section but as i see that the first spinner work correctly but the second work correctly in first time that i choose from spinner 1 but second time i choose it from it spinner 2 it uses the previous information that get form database plus the new information if it possible i can send my class to you if you want